# How to find out the name of JIT used when you run your java program

Tags: java, jit

Is there any command or something like that to know the name of JIT used when running the java program?

Comment: I am not sure if there is an internal API to figure that; worst case you could run "java -version" and parse the output of that.

Comment: @EddyG - that gives you the JVM version, not the JIT compiler name.

Comment: There isn't any way to know the JIT compllier my JVM is using? @StephenC

Comment: @Sank.P - Did you read aioobe's Answer?  That is how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer applies to OpenJDK Hotspot)

You should be able to use `-XX:+LogCompilation` to get a log file(hotspot_pid< PID>.log, in the startup directory) containing lines like

> <nmethod compile_id='2' **compiler='C1'** level='3' ...

**Note:**`LogCompilation` is a diagnostic VM-option. So you will need to enable it by preceding it with
`-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`. Your script line for running the class file would look like:

`java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation MyClass`

See this Oracle article, [Understanding Java JIT Compilation with JITWatch, Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1.html), for further details.

Note that there may be several different JITs in action during one execution.

Comment: Actually, i dont have any idea about what you said. can you elaborate how to use the above command you mentioned? @aioobe

Comment: Here's a [good article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1-2266278.html) on the subject.